# Would the classic example of a notes website be considered static, or dynamic?

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, static, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito

I've been battling with differentiating the two based on the definition of static. My understanding is, if the website loads the "same content", and is delivered as is, then it is static. But if users can login, and each have their own list of notes that are private to their account, does that make it dynamic?

The exact stack is Reactjs, webpack, cognito, DynamoDB.

The only "dynamic" aspect to what I'm building will allow users to text a phone number to add notes, which in this case I think needs an ec2 instance that parses the information, and adds it to the dynamodb, and even though the website shows it, it still would be categorized as static, and could be hosted on S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the nature of the core consideration.

The static vs dynamic distinction in this context depends solely on the nature of the server's role in processing the content returned by the web server.

As long as the web server -- S3 in this case -- does no processing, implements no logic, runs no code... that's the meaning of "static" in "static web site hosting."

> On a static website, individual web pages include static content. They might also contain client-side scripts. By contrast, a dynamic website relies on server-side processing, including server-side scripts such as PHP, JSP, or ASP.NET. Amazon S3 does not support server-side scripting.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Reactjs, webpack, and cognito can fit the description of "client-side scripts."

> text a phone number to add notes, which in this case I think needs an ec2 instance that parses the information, and adds it to the dynamodb

Or, Lambda with API Gateway could perform this part.

Your proposed site -- or, more correctly, the role of the web server in your site -- seems to meet the definition of "static" in the context of S3 static web site hosting.  S3 doesn't limit what your *site* can do, the limitations are on what S3 will do as part of making that site work.  All it will do is return static objects.